# fields.title.content in views-view-fields--n--block.html.twig won't display

Tags: theming, entities

This is what I wrote into **views-view-fields--n--block.html.twig**.
The second and third fields are displayed properly *(here I used the machine name)*. But how do I get the title which is automatically there with every content type?

```
<div class="field-1">
<h1> {{ fields.title.content}}</h1>
{{ fields.field_news_bild.content }}<br>
{{ fields.body.content}}</div>
```

please help!

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, did you add the Title as a field in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that my title fields' name is title_1.

this is what brought the solution:

```
 <ol>
    {% for key, field in fields %}
        <li>key: {{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

This shows all fields from the view in the template file.